# No member named dim in Halide::GeneratorInput<Halide::Func>

Tags: halide

I'm trying to translate the [resize app](https://github.com/halide/Halide/blob/master/apps/resize/resize.cpp#L113) from the halide repository from the inline declarations to a generator. Everything seems to work fine, except for this:

```
Func clamped = BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge(input);`
```

In the original code, `input` is declared like so `ImageParam input(Float(32), 3)`. In my generator, I've translated this to: `Input<Func> input { "input", Float(32), 3 }`. I'm then declaring the `clamped` in the exact same way as the original code. When compiling, I'm getting this error:

```
Halide.h:15202:50: error: no member named 'dim' in 'Halide::GeneratorInput<Halide::Func>'
    object_bounds.push_back({ Expr(func_like.dim(i).min()), Expr(func_like.dim(i).extent()) });
                                   ~~~~~~~~~ ^
```

Is there a way to create a `BoundaryConditions::repeat_edge` on an `Input<Func>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, associate a Buffer<> with it. (Maybe a Buffer in your case, try it out).

```
 struct MyGen : Generator<MyGen> {
     Input<Buffer<>> dim_only_input_buffer{ "dim_only_input_buffer", 3 }; 
     ... 
  };
```

I ran into something similar, you can see more about this in this [github issue](https://github.com/halide/Halide/issues/2170)

Answer (score 1):

The idea of `Input<Func>` is that it may be instantiated with another `Func` when composing generators together. (E.g. the output of one generator may be the input to another and the graph of all connected generators is compiled as a single Halide program.) The problem is `Funcs` do not have fixed bounds like `Buffers` do. Hence one cannot ask for (e.g.) the width of a `Func`.

For a generator which is designed to always be used with concrete memory, one can use Input. To impose a boundary condition on an Input, the bounds need to be passed as explicit parameters to the generator. E.g. as other `Inputs`.